# Having trouble with multiple hosts on Apache Snow Leopard

Tags: apache, macos, osx-snow-leopard, virtualhost, multiple-sites

I am running Apache on my Mac OS X (Snow Leopard) machine. I want to be able to set up multiple hostnames so that I can develop and test multiple sites at the same time, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Here's what I've tried:

In my etc/hosts file I've set added these entries:

```
127.0.0.1    testsite1.localdev.com
127.0.0.1    testsite2.localdev.com
```

Then, in apache2/httpd.conf I have added these entries:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/www/development/testsite1
   ServerName testsite1.localdev.com
   <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/www/development/testsite1">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/www/development/testsite2
   ServerName testsite2.localdev.com
   <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/www/development/testsite2">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But happens is that both hostnames resolve to the first one listed in the httpd.conf file -- in this case, testsite1. If I switch their positions, then they both resolve to testsite2.

I've also tried changing the area that reads *:80 and replacing that with the specific hostnames for each site, but that has no effect.

I am being sure to reboot apache after each change.

Thanks for any help!

Gary

Comment: FYI everyone: I found the answer I needed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683891/how-to-fix-this-virtual-host-setup

Answer (score 1):

- in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf uncomment the vhost file like:

  ```
  # Virtual hosts
  Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
  ```
- in /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf use...

  ```
  #
  # Use name-based virtual hosting.
  #
  NameVirtualHost *:80

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
      ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>

  # local test site
  <VirtualHost *:80> 
    <Directory /Users/<youruser>/Sites/test>
      AllowOverride All 
    </Directory> 
    DocumentRoot "/Users/<youruser>/Sites/test"
    ServerName test.local
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Be sure that your  and Sites folders have permissions of 755

and be sure that you add to your /etc/hosts file...

```
# test
127.0.0.1   test.local
```